# React useState with className and styled components hover out

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement an animation both on the hover in and out. For hover in I use a normal css :hover. For hover out I tried to make a default state outside of the :hover but this means that when the page loads it already applies it. This is what I tried.

```
const Container = styled.div`
    animation-name: move-card-down;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    :hover {
     animation-name: move-card-up;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

@keyframes move-card-up {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
      transform: translateY(-1rem);
    }
  }

  @keyframes move-card-down {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-1rem);
    }

    100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
`
```

So I figured I could instead apply a class to the div whenever a user hovers over it for the first time instead on a page load.

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  const onMouseOverCard = (): void => {
    setHover(true);
  };

  const hovered = true === hover ? 'hovered' : '';

 <Container onMouseOver={() => onMouseOverCard()} className={`${hovered}`}>
 </Container>

const Container = styled.div`
 .hovered {
    animation-name: move-card-down;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
`
```

It applies my class to the section but it doesn't load the styles for it. Can someone tell me why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the transition part, but the toggling of classes should work fine, example: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-butterfly-qocvd?file=/src/App.js:0-291

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const MyDiv = styled.div`
  color: red;
  &.foobar {
    outline: dashed;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  const [klass, setKlass] = useState("");

  return (
    <MyDiv
      className={klass}
      onMouseEnter={() => setKlass("foobar")}
      onMouseLeave={() => setKlass("")}
    >
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </MyDiv>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in my question. It actually does put the class onto the div but then it doesn't "load" the styles for it. When I inspect the element I also don't see them at all

Comment: I edited my response, you need to add the `&` in the styled css definition